# Odoo: How to create many records in Transient.Model?

Tags: python, odoo, record, wizard

This code only creates one record. What is wrong?

```
class PartnerTagCreate(models.TransientModel):

    """ Choose tags to be added to partner."""
    _name = 'partner.tags.create'
    _description = __doc__

    market_id = fields.Many2one('partner.tags', string='Market Tag')
    application_id = fields.Many2one('partner.tags', string='Application Tag')
    partner_id = fields.Integer()

    @api.multi
    def create_contact_tag(self):

        for record in self.env['sale.order.line'].browse(self._context.get('active_ids', [])):

            vals = {}
            vals['partner_id'] = record.order_partner_id

            self.write(vals)
        return True
```

I need this function to create one record for each `order_partner_id` I selected before opening the wizard...

How to achieve that?

Here my new code (function) ...

```
def create_contact_tag(self):
    sale_order_line_ids = self.env['sale.order.line'].browse(self._context.get('active_ids', []))
    for partner in sale_order_line_ids:
        values = {}
        values['partner_id'] = partner.order_partner_id
        self.create(values)
    return {}
```

This creates one record for marketing_id and/or application_id and dedicated records for each partner_id in the record.

Comment: the code looks like you just "rewrite" the partner_id for that specific TransientModel. You don't "create" at any moment.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I already tested it with "create" and it creates me one record with the market_id and application_id and n records for n selected records (in my case sale.order.line). I want to have n records with market_id, application_id and the partner_id (one record for each partner_id without double records). Best regards, Paul

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand the new point, can you post a new question with the new situation?

Comment: I added my current code ... I hope it helps you. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You use the 'create' method to create new records; this is the same for TransientModel as for the persistent Model.
So, replace

```
self.write(vals)
```

by

```
self.create(vals)
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I already tested this and it creates me one record with the market_id and application_id and n records for n selected records (in my case sale.order.line). I want to have n records with market_id, application_id and the partner_id (one record for each partner_id without double records). Best regards, Paul

Comment: Re-reading your question with this information makes it clear that there are multiple issues with your code: Why is partner_id only an Integer, not a Many2One ('res.partner')?  How is your method create_contact_tag() called? (It seems some more code is missing) You need to set all values to the vals dict before creating records, including the market_id, application_id. Where should these come from?  Why are you naming your loop variable "partner", even though it iterates over sale_order_line_ids? (in your new code).
I'm afraid these are too many questions to give you a good answer...